# How to compare AliasSeq's in D

Tags: metaprogramming, d

Examples in std.meta suggest to use `is(AliasSeq!(...) == AliasSeq!(...))`, but this fails in cases like this:

```d
static assert(is(TypeTuple!(3, int, "Zorro") == TypeTuple!(3, int, "Zorro")));
```

The example comes from [the news group](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/vsqrjipekxtfnpddcqtz@forum.dlang.org). In the same thread, there is a hint to use foreach to compare aliases one by one, but I found that the following is shorter and works well:

```d
struct X(S...) {}
static assert(is(X!(AliasSeq!(3, int, "Zorro")) == X!(AliasSeq!(3, int, "Zorro"))));
```

or

```d
static assert(is(X!(3, int, "Zorro") == X!(3, int, "Zorro")));
```

Do you know if there's any situation when this fails? Is there any better method to 100% reliably compare `AliasSeq`s?

Comment: note that the `AliasSeq` in there is redundant; it is automatically expanded into itself for the template argument list. But I think what you have works.